# SASS mixin with boolean variable: If-Statement not working

Tags: scope, sass, mixins

I'm creating a mixin which styles an `$element`'s `$property` to generate page-specific CSS. (Background: There are four pages with different color schemes).

**Not working mixin (with if-statement):**

```scss
@mixin themify($element, $property, $color-light: false) {
     @if $color-light == "true" {
         $pages: home forestGreen, about darkOrange, work dodgerBlue, contact fireBrick;
     }
     @else {
         $pages: home darkGreen, about orange, work royalBlue, contact crimson;
     }
     @each $page in $pages {
         .page--#{nth($page, 1)} .#{$element} {
             #{$property}: nth($page, 2);
         }
     }
 }

 /* Call the mixin */
 @include themify(site-nav, background-color, $color-light: true);
```

**Error:**

```
error/style.scss (Line 47 of css/ui/_misc.scss: Undefined variable "$pages".)
```

### Update

Adding `$pages: "";` before the if-statement helps. Why?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**You need to have a default `$pages` defined outside the `@if` clause.**
It is a scope issue ... the `@if` clause is a narrower scope than your mixin ... so anything defined inside would be private to that scope.

Try it like this:

```
@mixin themify($element, $property, $color-light: false) {
    $pages: ();
    @if $color-light == true { // boolean check not string
        $pages: home forestGreen, about darkOrange, work dodgerBlue, contact fireBrick;
    }
    @else {
        $pages: home darkGreen, about orange, work royalBlue, contact crimson;
    }
    @each $page in $pages {
        .page--#{nth($page, 1)} .#{$element} {
            #{$property}: nth($page, 2);
        }
    }
}

/* Call the mixin */
@include themify(site-nav, background-color, $color-light: true);
```

[DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/8615883)

Comment: Yup, exactly. Already updated my question before. Why is this needed?

Comment: Also, be careful when checking against booleans as a string. In this case, passing (true) as an argument fails the check; comparing against == true instead of "true" should be safer!

Comment: another way to avoid the original error is to set a default state for the variable `$pages` and change the value only if `$color-light` is `true`. Which reduce 3 lines of your code, since `@else` statement will not be needed. The original state should be darker version, then change value to light version if `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Message error could be confusing, but you have syntax error. It should be `@else` not `else`.

Comment: This is actually a typo and not present in my code. Thank you. It doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a small function to check boolean properly (for myself at least)

http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/a72a18f259c9c18ab773300b197bd08a

```
  // ----
  // libsass (v3.3.6)
  // ----

  // CHECK BOOLEAN VALUE
  @function bool($value: false) {
      @if $value == false or 
          $value == "" or 
          $value == "false" or 
          $value == 'false' or
          $value == 0 {
              @return false;
          }
      @return true;
  }


  // Lets test
  $var1: false;

  @if bool($var1) == true {
    /* This value is true */
  } @else {
    /* This value is false */
  }
```

Comment: Would you care to include the code you wrote in your answer so it’ll be available when the site isn’t available?